# nodejs - How to determine type of javascript object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using `express.js` on `node.js`. I have used `seneca` microservices after promisifying them using `bluebird` hence making a promise chains with all my service calls.

Now, in the `catch()` block of my promise chain in case of an error an error object is passed which on `console.error(err)` prints:

```
[ReferenceError: number is not defined]
```

What kind of object is this?

`console.error(JSON.stringify(err));` prints:

```
{}
```

`console.log(err instanceof Array);` prints:

```
false
```

`console.log(Object.keys(err));` prints:

```
[]
```

`console.log(typeof err);` prints:

```
object
```

Also, how do I differentiate it from an empty `{}`?

Comment: There's nothing called JSON Object. Moreover, it is JavaScript Object Notation. Try `err instanceof Error`?

Comment: What you are after is probably the name of the "class", not the type